# Label and ProgressBar not showing in Grid in WPF C# application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to show a Label and ProgressBar control in a Grid control in WPF, but the controls are not showing. Here is the XAML code for the Grid control:

```
`<Window x:Name="frmProgress" x:Class="CheckitWPF.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CheckitWPF"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="Progress" Height="75" Width="460" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStyle="None">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="61*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="21*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label x:Name="lblProgress" Content="Progress" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22" FontSize="8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
    <ProgressBar x:Name="progress" Height="10" Margin="18,0,14,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
</Window>`
```

What could be the problem?

I have tried rebuilding the project, but the controls are still not showing. I have also tried changing the Content property to Children, but that didn't work either.

Comment: looks like you're missing the column in which label and progbar shall appear.
<Label x:Name="lblProgress" Content="Progress" Grid.column="0" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="22" FontSize="8" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />

Comment: Try specifying the columns for each control and try setting the row definitions too if you want that in row wise.
Grid.Column = 0 for label
Grid.Column = 1 for progeress bar

Samething for row if you want it.

Grid always places elements one above the other, imagine as a stack.